# Can you use counts in sklearn logistic regression input?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, bernoulli-probability

So, I know that in R you can provide data for a logistic regression in this form:

`model <- glm( cbind(count_1, count_0) ~ [features] ..., family = 'binomial' )`

Is there a way to do something like `cbind(count_1, count_0)` with sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression? Or do I actually have to provide all those duplicate rows?  (My features are categorical, so there would be a lot of redundancy.)

Answer (score 0):

If they are categorical - you should provide binarized version of it. I don't know how that code in R works, but you should binarize your categorical feature always. Because you have to emphasize that each value of your feature is not related to other one, i.e. for feature "blood_type" with possible values 1,2,3,4 your classifier must learn that 2 is not related to 3, and 4 is not related to 1 in any sense. These is achieved by binarization.

If you have too many features after binarization - you can reduce dimensionality of binarized dataset by FeatureHasher or more sophisticated methods like PCA.

Comment: Perhaps my question was unclear. I know how to make a dummy matrix. I was asking about how to, rather than sending in rows with indicator variable 1 and 0, instead sum over all identical rows, and send in (80 1's, 10, 0's), rather than 90 rows with all the same features.

Comment: @Erin, Hmm, still I don't understand what you mean. Maybe you want to use sparse-matrix? By "row" you mean separate sample of your dataset?

Comment: I thought sparsity referred to the features, not the outcome. I found a way to do it with statsmodels instead of sklearn [here](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/examples/notebooks/generated/glm.html).